# c#: How is Monitor.Wait Implemented?

Tags: c#, multithreading, condition-variable

How is the Monitor.Wait() method implemented inside of the system.threading.monitor class of C#?

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28785/Thread-synchronization-Wait-and-Pulse-demystified

Conceptually, I'm envisioning something like this:

```
   class Monitor {
       public static Wait(object o) 
       {
           // Release Lock
           Monitor.Exit(o);

           // Spinlock until another Thread acquires Lock
           while(!Monitor.isEnter(o));

           // Wait to re-acquire lock
           Monitor.Enter(o);
       }
   }
```

It this accurate? Or Is there anything i'm missing?

Here's the typical monitor class example I'm considering as a bases for the preceding code.

```
using System.Threading;

readonly object o = new object();

// In Thread #1: (Where appropriate) 
lock(o) {
    Monitor.Wait(o);
}

//In Thread #2:  (Where appropriate) 
lock(o) {
    Monitor.Pulse(o);  
}
```

And Lock(o) is of course a built-in c# shortcut for:

```
try {
    Monitor.Enter(o);
    {
        //Lock Block Here
    }
}
finally {
    Monitor.Exit(o);
}
```

Comment: [System.Threading.Monitor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs)

Comment: The article linked to in your question effectively answers it as far as I can tell. What extra info are you looking for?

Comment: As a way to better understand the wait function, I was curious if its possible to re-implement it as simple function using what's already given as a published .Net APIs.   It easier to understand as just code...

Comment: Then I hope your C is good... ;) I'll update my answer in the next short while...

Answer (score 4):

To truely see if there's a simpler way to implement `Monitor.Wait`, we'd ahve to investigate how it functions at a low level. The actual implementation is ultimately written in C and hidden from us but specifically for `Monitor.Wait(object)`, we can trace the chain of calls in the following manner;

```
Monitor.Wait(o)
-- return Monitor.Wait(o, -1, false)

Monitor.Wait(o, -1, false)
-- Monitor.ObjWait(false [exitContext], -1 [millisecondsTimeout], o)
```

From here it's harder to see what's going on even in ILSpy. As per Tigran's link to the source of the `Monitor` object, we're left with the following in the source;

```
    /*========================================================================
** Waits for notification from the object (via a Pulse/PulseAll). 
** timeout indicates how long to wait before the method returns.
** This method acquires the monitor waithandle for the object 
** If this thread holds the monitor lock for the object, it releases it. 
** On exit from the method, it obtains the monitor lock back. 
** If exitContext is true then the synchronization domain for the context 
** (if in a synchronized context) is exited before the wait and reacquired 
**
    ** Exceptions: ArgumentNullException if object is null.
========================================================================*/
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    private static extern bool ObjWait(bool exitContext, int millisecondsTimeout, Object obj)
```

The description is left fairly self-explanitory into what's it's doing and in what sequence. However, the precise implementation by which it does so is wrapped from various `private static extern` methods which contain the crucial code.

`extern` [specifies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern) that the actual implementation lies in another assembly. It may be used with `DllImport` when accessing unmanaged code (not the case here) or could be an [extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias). From here as per SO post [asking about where to find the implementation of extern methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16587170/1838819), you'd have to look at the C code itself which can be found in the [Core CLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e0486761d6c019cb696dcd35aeecc031b1d01eef/src/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp) (credit Scott Chamberlain).

From here we're looking at the C method implementation for `ObjWait()` which [maps](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/238907f69662dda53dee0afd9848756a5bb790e9/src/vm/ecalllist.h#L1027) (line 1027) to `ObjectNative::WaitTimeout` in the CLR;

```
FCIMPL3(FC_BOOL_RET, ObjectNative::WaitTimeout, CLR_BOOL exitContext, INT32 Timeout, Object* pThisUNSAFE)
{
    FCALL_CONTRACT;

    BOOL retVal = FALSE;
    OBJECTREF pThis = (OBJECTREF) pThisUNSAFE;
    HELPER_METHOD_FRAME_BEGIN_RET_1(pThis);

    if (pThis == NULL)
        COMPlusThrow(kNullReferenceException, W("NullReference_This"));

    if ((Timeout < 0) && (Timeout != INFINITE_TIMEOUT))
        COMPlusThrowArgumentOutOfRange(W("millisecondsTimeout"), W("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));

    retVal = pThis->Wait(Timeout, exitContext);

    HELPER_METHOD_FRAME_END();
    FC_RETURN_BOOL(retVal);
}
FCIMPLEND
```

Before getting into this, it's worth looking at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/Documentation/botr/mscorlib.md) (also credit Scott Chamberlain), which states;

> FCalls are identified in managed code as extern methods with the MethodImplOptions.InternalCall bit set.

This explains our link to `ObjWait()` and `ObjectNative::WaitTimeout`. So, breaking this down further, we can see basic `null` and argument checks with appropriate exceptions raised if so. The crux is the call to `pThis->Wait()`...at which point I can't quite trace further...yet.

From here we get to `Object::Wait` ([line 531](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/377073385e4545d36e1a96429dd78548f87c597c/src/vm/object.h#L531)), then going to `SyncBlock::Wait` ([line 3442](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e0486761d6c019cb696dcd35aeecc031b1d01eef/src/vm/syncblk.cpp#L3442)). At this point we have most of the meat of the implementation and there's quite a bit to it.

Given all of the above and getting back to what you asked re a simpler implementation, I'd be wary of simplifying `Monitor.Wait()`. There is a *lot* going on under the hood and it'd be very easy to make a mistake and have potential bugs in an alternative implementation.

**EDIT**

Serious shout out to [Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain) who did most of the investigation below ILSpy-level and delving/debugging the C code stack. Pretty much all investigatory work below ILSpy-level is his, I've merely compiled it here into an answer.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e0486761d6c019cb696dcd35aeecc031b1d01eef/src/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp

Comment: @DiskJunky I started to post the same chain that you found, but hit a wall at the `pThis->Wait(Timeout, exitContext);` call in that method.

Comment: @DStanley yeah, I just hit that myself. I'll update my answer with findings to date while I investigate further

Comment: Your guess about Wait is incorrect, I got the solution for coreclr up and running so I can hit Go to Definition. `pThis->Wait` takes you to [`Object::Wait`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/377073385e4545d36e1a96429dd78548f87c597c/src/vm/object.h#L531) which has a `GetHeader()->Wait(timeOut, exitContext)` that takes you to [`ObjHeader::Wait`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e0486761d6c019cb696dcd35aeecc031b1d01eef/src/vm/syncblk.cpp#L2707), hopefully that will help you enough to keep tracking things down.

Comment: Did one more layer, `ObjHeader::Wait` has a `pSB->Wait(timeOut,exitContext)` that takes you to [`SyncBlock::Wait`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e0486761d6c019cb696dcd35aeecc031b1d01eef/src/vm/syncblk.cpp#L3442), that method has quite a bit of meat to it so I stopped there.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I'll be honest - this is far out of my depth! That said, I'll keep updating the answer with any detail and credit yourself. I *am* curious to get to the bottom of this though...there's a lot going on in that `Monitor.Wait()`

Comment: The easist way to look around the code is clone the repo, [build it](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e0486761d6c019cb696dcd35aeecc031b1d01eef/Documentation/building/windows-instructions.md) then open [the visual studio project](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e0486761d6c019cb696dcd35aeecc031b1d01eef/Documentation/workflow/EditingAndDebugging.md) for the managed or native code (you need to run a build once to get the `bin\obj\Windows_NT.<Arch>.<BuildType>\CoreCLR.sln` to exist to look around the native code). this lets you use tools like Go to Definition to jump around.